# How to control tabindex using a map on a VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have a pageBlockTable which uses a map to display successive columns.  When the user inputs a value and tabs out of the field, the focus goes to the input field in the next column, as expected, but immediately that field loses the focus.  How can I keep the focus on that field?

Upon further investigation, it appears that the issue is with the actionsupport; if that is not included, the tab works correctly.  Why would an action support call screw up the tab into the input field?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!measurementsByType[sec]}" var="meas" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!fieldsByType[sec]}" var="fld">
        <apex:column headerValue="{!columnHeadersByField[fld]}" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!meas.measurement[fld]}" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                    action="{!clearIdentifier}" />
             </apex:inputField>
         </apex:column> 
     </apex:repeat>
</pageBlockTable >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actionSupport without a reRender attribute causes the entire page to reload, so obviously the focus of the element will be lost, since you're actually navigating to a new page from the browser's perspective. Even with a reRender target, the focus will likely be lost because the platform will modify the DOM and likely cause the focus to be lost. If you want to still use the actionSupport, you need to (a) use a reRender target, and (b) save and restore the input focus. That would look something like this:

```
<script>
var focused;
window.addEventListener('focus', ev => if(ev.target.id) focused = ev.target.id);
<script>

...

<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="" 
    action="{!clearIdentifier}" 
    oncomplete="if(focused) document.getElementById(focused).focus(); focused = null" />
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.  It turned out the actionSupport worked with just a rerender="", with nothing in quotes.